# How to create hyperlink from a pdf to another pdf to a specified page using itext

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, itext

I am using itext to create a pdf. As a final result i am downloading a zip file.After extracting it i am having directory structure as follows:-

```
main dir
|
|_ evidence_dir/abc.pdf
|
|_xyz.pdf
```

i am using this code to create the link in pdf

```
chunk = new Chunk( "Link" ).setAction(PdfAction.gotoRemotePage("evidence_dir/abc.pdf", "6", false,  true   ));
```

this code is for file xyz.pdf. I am getting the link create but when clicking on the link current pdf getting closed and then nothing happened.

Can anybody please help me.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've create a small standalone example that shows how to create a [RemoteGoto](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/RemoteGoto) in a PDF using iText. You can download the ZIP with the resulting PDFs [here](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/results.zip). It works for me, can you check if it works for you?

Several things aren't clear from your question.

- Is `"6"` present as a named destination in your `abc.pdf`? (I created an `abc.pdf` file with a destination named `"dest"`)
- Is `"6"` a named destination defined by a PDF string? (cf. your `false` parameter)
- Are you aware of the limitations of opening a new PDF viewer window? (cf. your `true` parameter)

**Update:**
In your comment, you say that `"6"` should be a number, but in your code, you use a string. It's normal that *that doesn't work*, strings aren't numbers. Please take a look at the [RemoteGoToPage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/RemoteGoToPage) example to see how it's done.

**Update 2**
In one of the comments, I'm asked if you can link to a specific word in an existing PDF from an HTML-link. That's a completely different question. You can do this using [Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf). On page 7 of this spec, you can find more info about the `search` parameter:

> Opens the Search UI and performs a search for the specified  word list
>   in the document. Matching words are highlighted  in the document.

Comment: "6" is the page no of destination pdf i want to open.

Comment: No i am not aware about limitation of opening that in new window.Is there any thing that i should know.

Comment: Many people think that it means that you can open a new browser window. When used as a browser plug-in, the viewer ignores that parameter. Also: the action only works when you really unzip the document. It doesn't work if you open the ZIP file, for instance in Windows explorer.

Comment: it is not working to go to particular page in the another pdf.Can you please tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: You're using a string instead of a number for the page number. Please take a look at my answer. I've added an update with an example that jumps to page 6 of a remote document.

Comment: Hi Bruno,I think example is not working because in example link was created to jump to 6'th page of the remote page but after downloading the zip file from example when i click on the link it is opening the first page of remote pdf.

Comment: The PDFs that are zipped into this ZIP-file http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/results2.zip show the correct behavior in Adobe Reader. If they "don't work" for you, it's not an iText problem, but a problem with your viewer. Which viewer are you using?

Comment: oh yes you are right.I was using document viewer "evince ".After opening it in kpdf it is working fine.Thanks a lot.You made my day.

Comment: I just want to ask one more thing is there any method through which we can jump to a remote pdf having a particular text by clicking on a link.

Comment: You can do this by adding a "named destination" to the target PDF. For instance in the first example in my answer, I created a named destination `dest` in `abc.pdf`. This way, I can jump to this position.

Comment: but text will be availaible at run time how i can determine which text should be made as destination name.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maybe you're asking something that is impossible. Have you ever seen PDFs that show the behavior you're looking for? (If not, that could be an indication that PDF doesn't allow that kind of functionality.) What do you know about `abc.pdf` when creating `xyz.pdf` and are you able (or allowed) to change `abc.pdf`?

Comment: i just when my destination pdf get's opened it automatically searched for the particular string if i can pass it somehow while giving destination path.

Comment: sorry i forget to tell you calling hyperlink will be in html page not in pdf but destination will be pdf.

Comment: That's a completely different discussion. If you want to link to a word in a PDF from an HTML link, you can do so with the search parameter. Please read http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf for more info.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it's also about opening PDF search automatically from an HTML page, but note that the document I refer to isn't part of the ISO standard. It explains how Adobe implemented open parameters in Adobe Reader and Acrobat. Other vendors may or may not support this functionality...